# Angular byte64 conversion to pdf returns #Blocked

Tags: download, angular6, pdf-generation, decode

Working on converting the base64 stream data that is returned from my java service response to download as a PDF on my angular application, using the atob() to decode and then adding it to a download function.
The conversion is happening right, but while download there is some error that is happening that intern returns a #blocked blank screen, attached image below.
Also this is my part of the code for the same function, would request assistance on what possibly could be the issue, thanks in advance

```
onSubmitPropPreviewPDF() {
        console.log(this.propNo)
        let formValueProp: any = {
            trans_code: this.propNo.data.trans_code,
        }
        this.policyService.propPreviewPDF(formValueProp)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(previewdata => {
                this.previewdata = previewdata,
                    console.log('previewdata: ', previewdata);
                console.log(atob(this.previewdata.data.pdf_ccnt));
                const linkSource = (atob(this.previewdata.data.pdf_ccnt));
                console.log(linkSource);
                const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                console.log(downloadLink);
                const fileName = "sample.pdf";
                downloadLink.href = linkSource;
                console.log(linkSource);
                downloadLink.download = fileName;
                console.log(linkSource);
                console.log(downloadLink);

                downloadLink.click();

                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error


            }
            )
    }
```

[image: Blocked image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Chromium commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/413468f8e2196ea59444399c517a3a6b72fa86c3%5E%21/):

> Add #blocked suffix to about:blank URLs output from FilterURL.
>
> RenderProcessHost::FilterURL performs some security checks whether the
>   URL coming from the renderer process is a valid one. In some cases it
>   rewrites the URL to about:blank to avoid committing URL that is not
>   valid for the renderer process.
>
> This CL adds a #blocked reference fragment to the URL, so it is easier
>   to spot when this logic has taken effect and distinguish it from regular
>   navigations to about:blank URLs.

Does your sample.pdf is displayed properly in a simple html page with `<embed>` or `<a>` with base64 data url ?

Try converting your sample.pdf to [base64](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/pdf) and display it on test page to verify if it's well formatted:

```html
<embed  type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,xxx_your_base64_pdf_xxx"/>
```

Or try to download it via right click on download link:

```html
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,xxx_your_base64_pdf_xxx">download</a>
```

You could also use library like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to carry on download step if your PDF is correctly formatted.